# The SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized. MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, signalr-hub

It turns out that I'm working with SignalR, where in the html view I make the following request to the client:

```
 var myHub = $.connection.myHub;
    var direccionWeb = $("#direccionWeb").val().toString();
    $.connection.hub.url = direccionWeb + "/signalr";
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        myHub.server.broadcastMessageToPrinterReportTicket(global_venta, global_mesa, nombregarzon, idgrupo, grupo);

    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

In the Hub file I have the following:

```
public void BroadcastMessageToPrinterReportTicket(String global_venta,String global_mesa,String nombregarzon,String idgrupo, String grupo)
{
    string namePrinter = group;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string sql = "SELECT " +
        "cant," +
        "det " +
        "FROM producto " +                
        "WHERE venta=@global_venta AND venta>0 AND menu.grupo=@idgrupo AND comandasd.pedido=0";
    conexion.conectar(); 

    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion.con))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@global_venta", global_venta);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idgrupo", idgrupo);
        using (MySqlDataAdapter reader = new MySqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
    conexion.cerrar();


    Clients.All.printReport(datos, ........);
}
```

The file that contains the connection class is the following:

```
public void conectar()
{
    try
    {
        string ip = HttpContext.Current.Session["ip"].ToString();
        string db = HttpContext.Current.Session["db"].ToString();
        string user = HttpContext.Current.Session["user"].ToString();
        string pass = HttpContext.Current.Session["pass"].ToString();

        con = new MySqlConnection("server=" + ip + ";user id=" + user + ";password=" + pass + ";database=" + db + ";port=3306;Allow User Variables=true"); 
        con.Open();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

But when I try to add data to the DataTable, that is, on the line where sda.Fill (dt) says, the following error appears: the SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

The strange thing that when I use it is the same function declared in the controller, it works correctly. What I want is to be able to obtain a datatable with the parameters that BroadcastMessageToPrinterReportTicket receives and send it to the client.

If someone knew how to correct the error, or some help, it would be appreciated.

regards

Comment: Are you able to confirm if you have an actual session via the hub? I would suspect not, meaning your connection string does not contain an IP, Db, user or pass. Also, is there a reason you're using sessions to store your DB creds, and not, say the web.config?

Comment: @Darren
Tengo un archivo clase que uso para conectarme. Puede ser que el motivo es por que estoy trabajando con variables de session en el archivo.
Las variables de session del archivo clase de conección las necesito para rescatar sus valores y trabajarlos

Comment: @Danilo This is the main English language site, but there are other, like [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com) if that's a more convenient language for you to communicate in.

Comment: I apologize for the language, I told them that I have a class file that I use to connect. It may be that the reason is because I am working with session variables in the file. I need the session variables of the connection class file to rescue their values and work them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized

The `MySqlCommand.Connection` property needs to be set before the command can be used. The exception is telling you that it hasn't been set.

You're using the constructor that sets it:

```
using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion.con))
```

The logical inference is that `conexion.con == null`.

We see that `con` is set in `conectar`. However, there is a `try`/`catch` block around that code. Therefore, it must be the case that an exception is being thrown (and ignored) before `con` is assigned.

The most likely explanation is that one (or more) of the `HttpContext.Current.Session["..."]` values is `null`, so calling `.ToString()` on it throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Recommendations:

1. Don't catch and ignore exceptions; they often indicate a real problem that needs to be handled correctly.
2. Session state seems like a very odd place to store database credentials; look into using web.config settings instead. (Or you may wish to just start by hard-coding them to see if you can get the rest of your code working, then move them to `Settings` once you know everything else is correct.)

Comment: You're right. In my case I use session variables that work correctly, but I realized that when I call the connection file from the HUB file of signalR, the session variables are deleted, and even if I declare any session variable, it does not allow it because I get an error. I see that for some reason it does not let me work with session variables

Comment: @Danilo if this answered the question, please accept the answer (by clicking the "tick" icon).

Comment: I found the solution, what happens is that in the Hub, it does not work with session variables, so I had to replace it with global variables, since in the connection file I had session variables